# Why do static pages work in Python Flask but endpoints give 502 bad gateway error?

Tags: nginx, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, gunicorn

First of all, I realize that there can be many reasons for this problem. First of all, let me write down what I use:

- PostegreSQL
- Python
- Flask
- Nginx
- Gunicorn
- Cloudflare

My Python Flask web application is running with all its features on both my Windows and Ubuntu local server.

When I deploy to VPS, static pages are opened and I can navigate the pages.

However, when I want to register as a user to my web application, it waits for a long time and I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.

I deployed the application in a virtual environment in the VPS. Nginx and Gunicorn status are ok, succesful and active.

In my main application code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

that's part of it.

I also created a file called wsgi.py, and here's what it contains;

```
from myapp import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Yes I would like to send you the logs but I am so confused that I don't know where and what to check.